# Induced fibration of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

How does the inclusion $\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Q$ induce a fibration
$K(\mathbb Z,n)\rightarrow K(\mathbb Q,n)$ with fibre $\Omega K(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z,n)$?

Comment: This really isn't a great question, since it is not at all clear where your difficulty lies. One can define a functor $K(-, n)$ (as in my answer), and that's really all there is to it. (I had trouble deciding whether to answer at all, and whether this question would be better suited for math.stackexchange.com. It's definitely not a research-level question; see the faq.) 

Comment: This is a very simple exercise. 

Comment: I have now deleted my answer, since the question has been changed. You have to choose your models correctly to get this fiber in a point-set topology sense, but it isn't hard. 

Comment: It's still the same very simple exercise I used to solve as an **undergraduate** student.

Comment: @Fernando Muro : very simple?? :) thanks anyway fernando.

Comment: @palio, indeed, definitely not at a research level

Comment: Just a remark; Neil Strickland's answer certainly works, but there is a much easier way to see this fact (at least, I consider it easier); namely use Yoneda over and over again (once to get the map, once to check the homotopy lifting property, and again to compute the homotopy groups of the fiber). 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most functorial approach is to use the Dold-Kan equivalence 
$$F:\{\text{chain complexes}\} \to \{\text{simplicial abelian groups}\}. $$
Let $A_{\ast}$ denote the chain complex with just $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ in dimension $n-1$, let $B_{\ast}$ be the one with a surjective differential from $\mathbb{Q}$ in dimension $n$ to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ in dimension $n-1$, and let $C_{\ast}$ be the one with just a $\mathbb{Q}$ in dimension $n$.  There is an evident short exact sequence (and therefore fibration) $A_{\ast}\to B_{\ast}\to C_{\ast}$, which gives a fibration $|FA_{\ast}|\to |FB_{\ast}|\to |FC_{\ast}|$ of topological abelian groups.  Here $|FA_{\ast}|$ and $|FC_{\ast}|$ are $K(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},n-1)$ and $K(\mathbb{Q},n)$ essentially by definition, and it is easy to produce a weak equivalence from the corresponding model for $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ to $|FB_{\ast}|$.